# TFS 2013 migration to VSTS

Tags: tfs

I have a simple question I am migrating tfs 2013 update 4 to vsts and I am using a microsoft's migration tool but I have come across an error which stats it cant fetch my collections installation path (error tf255003), I read somewhere that the migration tool which was provided by microsoft is only supported for migration tfs2017 or tfs2017 update 1 to vsts. So can I not migrate a tfs 2013 directly to vsts, or first I have to upgrade the TFS2013 TO TFS2017 UPDATE1 then do the migration please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

We recommend you upgrade to TFS 2017 update1 first, then following the **[Migration Guide](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/migrate-tfs-vsts/?utm_source=ms&utm_medium=guide&utm_campaign=vstsdataimportguide)** step by step to do the migration.

For upgrading TFS 2013 to TFS 2017 update1, you can reference below articles:

- [Upgrading from TFS 2013 to TFS 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rob/2016/12/22/upgrading-from-tfs-2013-to-tfs-2017/)
- [Upgrade to Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2017.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/11/30/upgrade-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-2017/)

However, if you want to migrate from TFS 2013 directly, you can get and upload the source code manually, and [use Execl to export and import the work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel).

You can also have a try for [VSTS Sync Migration Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration),it allows you to bulk edit and migrate data between Team Projects on both Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

Besides, you can also use [OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility](http://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/), the Commercial Edition supports migration from either TFS or VSTS to either TFS or VSTS.

Comment: @The Man, Have you resolved your issue by the workarounds above?